# Why can't the Windows installer find my SATA drive when Linux can?

Tags: windows, hard-drive, sata

I built a computer from some old parts, including a SATA drive. If I boot from the Windows Vista installation DVD, there are no options under "Where do you want to install windows?", implying that the installer can't find the drive.

BIOS does find the drive as I can choose to boot from it. I can also see the drive from an Arch Linux live CD, and mount its partition without problem.

The "SATA" setting in BIOS is set to "IDE" (not RAID).

What could the problem be?

Update: I get the same problem with the Windows 7 installer. The hard-drive is a Samsung SP2004C.

Answer (score 0):

Vista is quite an old operating system. If the hardware is newer than the OS drivers are often missing.

In your case try to set the SATA mode to `AHCI` - Vista contains an universal SATA AHCI driver and therefore should be able to use your SATA drive without 3rd party drivers.

Comment: There doesn't seem to be an AHCI option. I've got Phoenix AwardBIOS, and in `Integrated peripherals > IDE devices configuration > SATA mode`, there is only IDE and RAID to choose from.

Comment: Robert's answer could have been worded better: the problem (probably) is that the OS setup disc does not have the proper (chipset etc) driver available to access the drive. His solution was to try a fallback or alternate drive access mode in the BIOS. Another possible solution wouyld be to look for a prompt during the setup process that allows you to provide a driver on cd which you might download from the mfg. website.